# Displaying mxn images using Matplotlib

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib. I am trying to display a 32x32 (pixel) image in a subplot with some text underneath it. My requirement is that the image should not auto scale, because then it becomes pixelated which I dont want. Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
plt.rcParams['toolbar']='None'
image=plt.imread("Test.jpg")
figsize=350/80,300/80
fig=plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray',extent=(1,32,32,64))
plt.axis('off')
str_comp_thinks="Text1 "
plt.text(-20,20,str_comp_thinks)
str_actual="Text2 "
plt.text(-20,25,str_actual)
plt.show()
```

I have tried several things, but I am not able to constrain the image to its original size. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I think this question has been asked before already. Are you sure to have searched thorough enough for a solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "autoscale"? Do you want to be able to change the figure size after plot creation?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want a matplotlib figure of X rows and Y columns, and show an image that is 32x32 pixels, in its original size and not scaled, and put two lines of text beneath the image. And yes, I have searched for a few days in a row and then only posted here for the experts.!

Comment: Would *all* subplots contain such 32x32 pixel images?

Comment: No I just need one image to be displayed at one time. So only the first subplot needs to have the image.

Comment: And what will the rest of the subplots show?

Comment: I wasn't planning to use the rest of the subplots. Essentially I am using subplots to just manage the intended layout of the figure

Comment: Great, so we can leave subplots out?! That makes everything much easier.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but is there a solution to my problem using matplotlib..? (hoping it was clear enough) or should  I look elsewhere.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Adjust the figure size and subplot parameters

You may adjust the figure size and subplot parameters such that the remaining space of the axes inside of the figure is exactly as large as needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['toolbar']='None'
image=np.random.rand(32,32)
dpi = 100

mleft = 100  # pixel
mright = 100 #
mtop= 30 
mbottom=200

figwidth= (image.shape[1]+mleft+mright)/float(dpi)
figheight = (image.shape[0]+mtop+mbottom)/float(dpi)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(figwidth,figheight))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=mleft/float(dpi)/figwidth,
                    right=1.-mright/float(dpi)/figwidth,
                    top=1.-mtop/float(dpi)/figheight,
                    bottom=mbottom/float(dpi)/figheight)

plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
str_comp_thinks="Text1"
fig.text(0.5,0.3,str_comp_thinks, ha="center")
str_actual="Text2"
fig.text(0.5,0.1,str_actual, ha="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using an OffsetImage inside the axes

The same can be achieved using an OffsetImage inside the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage,AnnotationBbox


plt.rcParams['toolbar']='None'
image=np.random.rand(32,32)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2.5), dpi=100)
imagebox = OffsetImage(image, zoom=72./fig.dpi, cmap='gray')
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy=(0.5,.7), xycoords='data', bboxprops={"linewidth":0})

ax.add_artist(ab)
    
plt.axis('off')
str_comp_thinks="Text1"
fig.text(0.5,0.3,str_comp_thinks, ha="center")
str_actual="Text2"
fig.text(0.5,0.1,str_actual, ha="center")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @importanceofBeingErnest. This worked exactly as I wanted it to be..!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `interpolation='none'` in imshow & `extent=(0,32,32,64)`?

Comment: Yes I tried that earlier and now again, doesn't work for me.